# Ajax call to PHP script on submit of form not working

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, forms, validation

I have a form which gets validated via ajax and when submitted calls to updatepassword.php, which updates a database with the input of Password2.There's something wrong with the call to updatepassword.php though, because it won't work. Please let me know! Thank you. PHP file below all others.

```
<script>
function checkForm() {

    var pass = document.getElementById("oldpassword").value;
    var pass1 = document.getElementById("passwordnew1").value;
    var pass2 = document.getElementById("passwordnew2").value;

    if (pass == '' || pass1 == '' || pass2 == '') {
        alert("Fill All Fields");
    } else {

        var passcheck = document.getElementById("editpassword");
        var passcheck1 = document.getElementById("equalpasswords1");
        var passcheck2 = document.getElementById("equalpasswords2");

        if (passcheck.innerHTML == 'Must be 3+ letters' || passcheck1.innerHTML == 'Password too short' || passcheck2.innerHTML == 'Password too short') {
            alert("Fill Valid Information");
        } else {
            document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
        }
    }
}


function validate(field, query) {
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else { // for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState != 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById(field).innerHTML = "Validating..";
        } else if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById(field).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
        } else {
            document.getElementById(field).innerHTML = "Error Occurred. <a      href='index.html'>Reload Or Try Again</a> the page.";
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET", "validation.php?field=" + field + "&query=" + query, false);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function submitForm() {
    $("document").ready(function(){
        $(".ajaxcall").submit(function() {

            var data = {
                "action": "test"
            };

            data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                url: "updatepassword.php", 
                data: { Password2: $('#passwordnew2').val()} , 
                success: function(data) {
                    $("#check").html(
                       data["Password2"] 
                    );
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
    });
}
</script>
```

This is my HTML:

```
<body>
<form action="#" id="myForm" name="myForm" method="post" onsubmit="return   submitForm();" class="ajaxcall">
    <div class="container">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><p><b>My email:</b></p></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p><b>My password:</b></p></td>
                <td><p id="editpassword"></p><p id="insertpassword"><input id="oldpassword"     name="inputedPassword" onblur="validate('editpassword', this.value)"     type="password"></p></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p><b>My new password:</b></p></td>
                <td><p id="equalpasswords1"></p><input id="passwordnew1" name="Password1"   onblur="validate('equalpasswords1', this.value)" type="password"></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p><b>Confirm password:</b></p></td>
                <td><p id="equalpasswords2"></p><input id="passwordnew2" name="Password2"   onblur="validate('equalpasswords2', this.value)" type="password" > <input  type="button" value="Save" onclick="checkForm()"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>

<p id="check"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the updatepassword.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

$email = $_SESSION['email'];

?>


<?php    
if (is_ajax()) {
    if (isset($_POST["action"]) && !empty($_POST["action"])) { 
        $action = $_POST["action"];
        switch($action) { 
          case "test": test_function($email); break;
        }
    }
}


function is_ajax() {
    return isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) &&       strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest';
}

function test_function($email) {
    $inData = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
    $x = $inData["Password2"];

    define('DB_NAME', 'Name');
    define('DB_USER', 'User');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'Password');
    define('DB_HOST','HOST');

    $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

    if (!link) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

    if (!$db_selected) {
        die('Can\'t use'. DB_NAME. ': ' . mysql_error());
    }    


    $result = "UPDATE  `Name`.`Students` SET  `Password` =  '$x'  WHERE  `Students`.`StudEmail` = '$email'  ";
    if (!mysql_query($result)) {
        die('error: ' .mysql_error());
    }

    $return["json"] = json_encode($return);
    echo json_encode($return);

    $_SESSION['Password2'] = $x;
}
?>
```

Comment: can you make fiddle for better understanding ?

Comment: Define "won't work".  When you debug this, where *specifically* does it fail?  Does the JavaScript code execute?  Is there an error in the JavaScript console?  Is the AJAX request made?  Does it contain what you expect?  What is the server's response?  There's *a lot* of debugging here that we can't do for you.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6xz80u56/ I wouldn't know how to insert the PHP code on jsfiddle

Comment: The form works, the validation works, what isn't working is the ajax call to the updatepassword PHP. It won't change the database. As you can see, there's a <p id="check"></p> in which I check if the ajax call works by inserting here Password 2 when "success". But it's as if success can't be reached.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON data you are sending via POST is not directly available in your PHP the way you are trying to access it:

```
$return["Password2"]
```

You need to do

```
$inData = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

and then you can access `$inData["Password2"]`

Comment: It still won't work Rby! Now it's like this:

    function test_function($email){
       $inData = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
        $x = $inData["Password2"]

Comment: what exactly do you get?

Comment: I get nothing, the form submits but nothing happens. This is the code:


`'<script type="text/javascript">'
function submitForm() {
$("document").ready(function(){
  $(".ajaxcall").submit(function(){
    var data = {
      "action": "test"
    };
    data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      url: "updatepassword.php", 
      data: { Password2: $('#passwordnew2').val()} , 
      success: function(data) {
        $("#check").html(
          data["Password2"] 
        );

        
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
}`

Comment: And the php file is up there in the description, edited as you said

Comment: You need to debug your php and ajax code.  First, add an error callback function to the ajax method.  Second, in your php you are looking for $_POST["action"] but the data you are sending does not contain "action". It only has "Password2".  Third, you need to check that $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] actually exists.  It may not be available at all, in which case the method test_function($email) does not get called.  You can add var_dump($_SERVER) and var_dump($_POST) at the top of your code before you do anything to see what is available in these arrays.